# Word date modified changes spontaneously

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

How well known is this one. ALL the modified dates on hundreds of word  documents are different to day than they were on Friday. They have all changed by an hour.
Is this a bug or a feature.
My analysis: The clocks changed by an hour over the weekend, so helpfully, Microsoft has reset ALL of the modified dates across the entire system. Presumably in six months they will all change again.
A routine I run daily, that normally takes six minutes to pick up any changes or new documents, is today taking HOURS, and  recording hundreds of non existent changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an operating system issue; not a Word issue. And yes, it reflects the change in local time between standard and daylight savings/summer time. Any time-stamp dependent routine should take account of that.

Comment: That is INSANE. I modified a document three years ago at Noon, (at what ever the daylight saving it was noon) When I open the file in Friday, it says noon  When I come in on Monday, that document now reports it was modified at 11:00. But it hasn't been changed. And this is a feature of the operating system.?? Who on earth thinks that makes any sense? What was the thinking behind it? And more to the point, can I convert the two date times to a number and get them to be the same?